# Getting the full list of colors available in Emacs

Tags: colors, display, commands

When I run `list-colors-display` I get the following:

[image]

which I think is a very small subset of colors that my Emacs supports, isn't it?

For example, I know Emacs supports other colors (gray20, blue15, etc). Why am I not seeing them as a result of the `list-colors-display` command?

How can I see the full list?

In case it matters, my version is:

```
"GNU Emacs 25.0.95.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.5 (Build 15F34)) of 2016-06-20"
```

---

If I evaluate:

```
(defined-colors)
```

I get:

```
("alternateSelectedControlColor" "alternateSelectedControlTextColor" "controlBackgroundColor" "controlColor" "controlDarkShadowColor" "controlHighlightColor" "controlLightHighlightColor" "controlShadowColor" "controlTextColor" "disabledControlTextColor" "gridColor" "headerColor" ...)
```

Comment: Maybe version 25 does something different. When I run `ESC-x list-colors-display` on my Mac (Emacs 24.4 app), I see the same colors and layout that you post in your posting. BUT... the part that you are showing is at the very bottom of the list of colors that I see. It's as if your window scrolled to the bottom of the color list when it ran the command.

Comment: Exactly what @Kevin says, and looking at the code of `list-colors-display`, it would appear that the original poster is getting `nil` for `(defined-colors)`.  I would suggest that the original poster evaluate `(message "%s" (defined-colors))` and let us know what the results are.  I would also suggest downloading a fresh version of a nightly build from Emacs for OSX and see if it works as expected out-of-the-box.  https://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: Doing some back-tracing of the code, I see that during the build process, the function `(ns-list-colors)` is used to set up the variable `x-colors` and the original poster is suffering from a partial-list -- i.e., missing `"LightGreen" "light green" "DarkRed" "dark red" . . . "GhostWhite" "ghost white" "snow"` which precedes `"alternateSelectedControlColor" "alternateSelectedControlTextColor"`  Again, I strongly suspect the build itself -- something is broken -- try a new version from the link above.  It can be download and tested in about 3 minutes.

Comment: The colors you are seeing what you would see in the OS X Color Chooser, clicked the third icon from the left, and selected "Developer". I have Emacs 24.5.1 and have the same problem. This was not problem in previous releases -- I got the full Emacs color list.
   
i was running Emacs installed from MacPorts. Since its version was the same as the one advertised at the above link I didn't see any point in downloading it. Eventually I stopped being stubborn, downloaded it, and the problem is gone. Not good to have different behavior in 2 implementations of an application with the same version.

Comment: This appears to be exclusively a problem with the emacs-app port in MacPorts. If you compile Emacs yourself, you won't see this issue. The issue is exactly as @lawlist described. This problem is still an issue with emacs-app 26.1 from MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lawlist and @kevin commented, this was a problem with the nightly snapshot that I used. I re-installed Emacs:

```
brew install emacs --devel  --with-cocoa --with-gnutls  --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick
```

and the problem went away.

Comment: Error: invalid option: --devel